# GLES multiple output buffers

Tags: android, frame-buffer, opengl-es3

I'd like to write multiple values (not just the color and depth value) in one pass to avoid redundancy in vertex shader. Therefore, i attach multiple (let's say two) color buffers (e.g. textures) to a frame buffer object.
As i read, GLES 3.0 supports GLSL 3.0 which supports layout( location = # ) qualifiers. However, the shaders do not compile with the error message "Typename expected, found 'layout'\n"

Simple fragment shader example:

```
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec3 vNormal;
layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 color;
layout( location = 1 ) out vec3 normal;
void main() {
    color = texture2D( uTexture, vTexture );
    normal = normalize( vNormal );
}
```

I would expect color going to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and normal going to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1. So, is there a way to avoid multiple passes in GLES 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is easy: the line

```
#version 300 es
```

has to be put on top, otherwise it will be interpreted as GLES 2.0 code. Furthermore, `varying` is obsolete and has to be exchanged by `in` and `texture2D` is covered by `texture`.